# Is it okay to implement equals() and hashCode() on @Entity Model classes in Play Framework?

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, playframework-1.x

I have an `@Entity`-annotated `Model` class in my Play application, which I am stuffing into a `Set` to ensure uniqueness prior to saving to the database. Since the objects haven't been saved yet, they don't have a key value. So the comparison must be based on their properties.

I took a peek at the `equals()` implementation in `JPABase`, and it seems to explicitly make all entity objects unequal if they don't have a key yet.

So, my question(s):

1. Is it okay to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` in my `Model` subclasses?
2. If so, what is the best/correct way to do so? Should I call `super.equals()`, and how should I deal with the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend to implement `equals` or `hashCode` in application model class. The uniqueness should be ensured by database in the end. From the application's perspective, uniqueness is almost always imposed on a certain field, e.g. username or email etc. I've never met the case that data entity uniqueness is computed on the entire object via `hashCode` or `equals` method.